# Upserting a document in CosmosDb, but only if "newer"

Tags: concurrency, azure-cosmosdb, upsert

I need to update documents in a CosmosDb.

```
{
firstname: "...",
lastname: "...",...
lastmodified: "2022-01-13T12:06:18.712Z"
}
```

Due to "concurrency" ( i.e. multiple concurrent "updaters" ), the update ( or insertion, hence `Upsert`? ) should only take place if the data I update is "newer" ( `data.lastmodified` ) than the one already persisted.

What is the proposed way to achieve this?

In plain SQL I'd opt for:
`UPDATE address SET ... WHERE address.lastmodified < newdata.lastmodified`
or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

If `Upsert` had the possibility for specifying contraints when to effectively upsert ( i.e. `address.lastmodified < newdata.lastmodified` ), I'd use these. But I guess `ItemRequestOptions` is not meant for that?

"concurrency"-context: updates are being posted into a service bus queue and an event-triggered AzureFunction handles the Events. Chances are, that multiple Events for the same data end up "concurrently" in the queue and hence are being executed "concurrently"

Thx for your advices
Clemens ( being new to ComosDb et al )

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using partial document update with conditional update. You can use Add or Set patch operations and specify your WHERE clause of `WHERE address.lastmodified < newdata.lastmodified` to specify whether it executes or not.

For more information see, [Partial Document Updates in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update)

Comment: Thx Mark. I have a clarification question: as I always get a complete json-document/object, can I patch/replace the complete document?
E.g.
`await _container.PatchItemAsync<OfferDto>(id: "<unique id of document>", 
                    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("..."), 
                    patchOperations: new[] { PatchOperation.Replace("/", updatedOfferDto ) }, 
                    requestOptions: patchItemRequestOptions );`

Comment: You could but you can't just pass the entire document. You have to specify each individual path/property to patch which would be annoying and tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use etag to be sure that you are updating the latest version of your document.

for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).